# Magento 2 EE rebrands to Magento Commerce. Tag rename?

Tags: feature-request, tags, magento2, retagging

At Magento Live UK, a rebranding has been announced: for Magento 2 there will be no more **Magento Enterprise Edition**, it's just **Magento Commerce** (likewise, **Magento Community Edition** becomes **Magento Open Source**)

See: https://twitter.com/ProductPaul/status/879691167679557632

Currently, we have several EE related tags on the site:

- [magento-enterprise](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-enterprise) Synonyms: enterprise-edition, enterprise, magento-ee (suggested)
- [magento-enterprise-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-enterprise-2)
- [magento2-enterprise](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-enterprise)
- various ee-1.x and enterprise-1.x version tags

I think it would make sense to merge [magento-enterprise-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-enterprise-2) and [magento2-enterprise](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-enterprise) and rename it to [magento-commerce](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-commerce). The tags that are related to Magento 1 versions should stay as they are, as I expect that the versions still run under their old name.

I'm not sure about [magento-enterprise](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-enterprise) though. We should probably leave it as it is because most questions there are still related to Magento 1, and add a comment in the tag excperpt that refers to the new tag.

What do you think?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to tackle this. One thing is sure. the magento-enterprise tag should remain, as you said, for M1 EE version.

Comment: leave it as is and just add new tags , whoever uses/searches old tag probably knows the difference . if you can manipulate thismaybe just add the new tag side by side with old tags

Comment: Does SE support a synonymous type function for linking tags?

Comment: IMHO, leave tags as it is and promote `magento-commerce` tag here after.

Comment: Tag synonyms have existed on Stack Exchange [for a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92271/). They've been [confusing to use in practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms), admittedly. Probably easiest to have a moderator handle the actual synonymization, if you can agree as a community on what the synonyms should be (which in this case seems pretty straightforward, but what do I know about Magento).